# what is wrong with this query in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to create the following table in sas. There is no error showing however MaxDate is not shown up in the test table.

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE test AS 
  SELECT * FROM connection to mydb 

     (SELECT  a.acct_nr, 
              a.label 
              tmp.maxdate 

      FROM  (SELECT * FROM   sandbox_db.dw_mv30k ) as A 

      INNER JOIN (SELECT   lylty_acct_id, 
                           max(f.seg_dep_dt) as maxdate 
                      FROM prod_lylty_trans_vw.lylty_flown_flight f 
                  GROUP BY lylty_acct_id ) as tmp 

              ON  a.acct_nr=tmp.lylty_acct_id;);

    DISCONNECT FROM mydb;
QUIT;
```

The MaxDate column is not shown up in the table.

Comment: try to list all columns in outer select query like create table test as SELECT acct_nr, label, MaxDate from connection to mydb instead of using '*'

Comment: there is a comma missing after a.label in your post, typo or maybe the issue?

Comment: @hadis You're only displaying columns from `FROM  (SELECT * FROM   sandbox_db.dw_mv30k ) as A` - your `inner join` columns will never get displayed - we can help better if you can provide a reproducible example